# Problemas para sacar tamaño lista python

Tags: python, librería

Cuando ejecuto el programa me sale el siguiente problema:

```
    if len(lista) !=0:
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
[
```

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 lista=detectar.encontrarPosicion
    if len(lista) !=0:
        x1=lista.box[0]
        y1=lista.box[1]
        x2=lista.box[2]
        y2=lista.box[3]
```

`encontrarPosicion` pertenece a una "librería" creada por mi, `detectar=im.detectaccionActiva`, `im.py` es el archivo donde se encuentra las funciones como `encontrarPosicion`.

`encontrarPosicion` tiene el siguiente código:

```
def encontrarPosicion(self, frame, ManoNum = 0, dibujar =  True):
        xlista = []
        ylista = []
        box = []
        self.lista = []
        if self.rest.multi_hand_landmarks:
            miMano = self.rest.multi_hand_landmarks[ManoNum]  
            for id, lm in enumerate(miMano.landmark):
                h, w, c = frame.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * h), int(lm.y *w)
                xlista.append(cx)
                ylista.append(cy)
                self.lista.append([id, cx, cy])
                if dibujar:
                    cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 5, (0, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)

            xmin, xmax = min(xlista), max(xlista)
            ymin, ymax = min(ylista), max(ylista)
            box = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
            if dibujar:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin - 20, ymin -20), (xmax + 20, ymax + 20), (0,255, 0), 2)   
        return self.lista, box
```

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Asegúrate de que has escrito bien los nombres de las variables, y sobre todo... nunca utilices como nombre de variable una palabra reservada para otra cosa: `if len(list) !=0:` estás poniendo len(***LIST***), y `list` es una función que se utiliza para crear listas, y obviamente la función no tiene longitud, es una función no una lista! El error está literalmente diciéndote que las funciones no tienen longitud... no tienes más que leerlo. Si no sabes inglés... te recomiendo que lo aprendas, al menos algo básico, porque en programación se usa para todo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está línea

```
list=detectar.encontrarPosicion
```

asigna la variable `list` con una función. No le asigna el valor calculado por la función, sino que **el código** de la función.

El código de una función no tiene largo ...

Segundo, es pésima idea usar "list" como nombre de variable; hay que evitar palabras que Python usa para sus propios fines.

Tercero: asignas a "list" y a continuación preguntas por "len(lista)". Dos variables distintas

```
list=detectar.encontrarPosicion
    if len(lista) !=0:
```

Para arreglar tu programa primero debes llamar correctamente a la función `encontrarPosicion`, pasandole los argumentos que requiere.